# Different String value for each productFlavor

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I need to have a String that varies in value based on my app's `productFlavors`:

I need to have something like this:

```
    def flavorName = new String()

    productFlavors {
    closedBeta {
        versionName "1.0.0-BETA"
        flavorName = "closedbeta"
    }
    alpha {
        versionName "1.0.0-ALPHA"
        flavorName =  "alpha"
    }
    production {
        versionName "1.0.0-PROD"
        flavorName =  "prod"
    }
}
```

This code apparently does not work because it just sets the value of `flavorName` as the declaration for each `productFlavor` proceeds. How can I have static value of `flavorName` to each `productFlavor`?

Comment: What is your question or problem ?

Comment: @androidnoobdev this code apparently does not work because it just sets the value of flavorName as the declaration for each productFlavor goes

Comment: use a switch case statement to determine which version the user is using & based on it, you can set the flavourName.

Comment: how can I retrieve the current product flavor to put in the switch case statement?

Comment: possibly related to this unanswered question [Is there a way to change gradle variable value based on selected productFlavor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956182/is-there-a-way-to-change-gradle-variable-value-based-on-selected-productflavor)

Comment: What are you trying to do with `flavorName` in this context? If you are using it within the app, maybe what you need is different string resources per flavor?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java