# Create and access productFlavor variables in android's build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, hockeyapp

I've a multi flavor project which is built by a CI and published to HockeyApp.
Each flavor has an **applicationId** and an **apiToken**, which is stored in the flavor itself (to keep all important variables in one place):

```
    def token = null

    productFlavors {

    prod {
        applicationId "de.example.appname"

        buildConfigField 'String', 'FLAVOR_ID', '"0"'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'HOCKEY_APP_ID', '"1234567890"'

        token = "1q2w3e4r5t6z7u8i9o0p"
    }

    demo {
        applicationId "de.example.appname.demo"

        buildConfigField 'String', 'FLAVOR_ID', '"1"'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'HOCKEY_APP_ID', '"987654321"'

        token = "p0o9i8u7z6t5r4e3w2q1"
    }
}
```

On the same level like "productFlavors" there are the hockeyApp-settings:

```
    hockeyapp {
       apiToken = token
       releaseType = 0
       notify = 0
       status = 1
       notesType = 1
       notes = "Uploaded with gradle"
    }
```

For debugging the code I build & upload the .apk-file via terminal:

```
./gradlew uploadProdReleaseToHockeyApp [...]
```

Unfortunately the variable token of the prod-flavor is always overridden by the demo-value. So after each uploading process I get errors like

> Error response from HockeyApp: App could not be created.

because gradle tries to upload the prod-flavor with the demo-token.

**Here some additional basic data:**

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:4.0.0'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
classpath 'de.felixschulze.gradle:gradle-hockeyapp-plugin:3.5'
```

Based on my requirements, is there a solution to define flavor-variables and access them in the shown way?

Comment: This seems identical to [this unanswered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956182/is-there-a-way-to-change-gradle-variable-value-based-on-selected-productflavor?rq=1). See also [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java), which may provide a solution.

Comment: Hey found any solution yet?i am looking for the same.

Comment: @iMDroid take a look at my correct marked answer ;-)

Comment: @JU5T1C3 Great. thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this special case I found following answer:

Add the hockeyapp-task with your modifications needed

```
hockeyapp {
    apiToken = "not_required"
    releaseType = 0
    notify = 0
    status = 2
    teams = 1234
    notesType = 1
}
```

In the next step add flavor-based gradle tasks to modify you hockeyapp's apiToken:

```
task setDevReleaseApiToken << {
    hockeyapp.apiToken = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
}

task setProdReleaseApiToken << {
    hockeyapp.apiToken = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
}
```

These tasks are called in gradle's `whenTaskAdded`-task, you can simply "override" it like this:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'uploadDevReleaseToHockeyApp') {
        task.dependsOn 'setDevReleaseApiToken'
    } else if (task.name == 'uploadProdReleaseToHockeyApp') {
        task.dependsOn 'setProdReleaseApiToken'
    }
}
```

Everytime the task `uploadDevReleaseToHockeyApp` is called (manually or by CI..) the task `setDevReleaseApiToken` is called and the related apiToken is assigned.

Extend this schema for all other flavors if needed!

Answer (score 1):

Though the OP might not be looking for an answer anymore, someone other might stumble upon this thread (like I did when I was dealing with this problem) so I'd like to share a solution.

I was dealing with variables having effect on gradle procedure itself (not on the source code) so I couldn't use resValue or buildConfigField.

This problem can be solved by using the **settings.gradle** file. This file executes before build.gradle, so you can prepare all your variables using this condition:

```
include ':project...'
rootProject.name = 'name...' 

def VARIANT1 = "YourFlavorName";
        if((gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains(":assemble"+VARIANT1+"Debug"))||
    (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains(":assemble"+VARIANT1+"Release"))
        ||
    (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains(":generate"+VARIANT1+"DebugSources"))||(gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains(":generate"+VARIANT1+"ReleaseSources"))) {
          gradle.ext.variable = value
          gradle.ext.var...
            }
```

It is a bit of a work-around but what this does is it checks the build commands given by your Android Studio and searches for the flavor name inside. Conditions with ":generate" are just for Building, ":assebmle" is for Running the application on a device.

Any variable you create in your settings file like this can be accessed from your **build.gradle** file.

```
myVariable = gradle.ext.variable
```

This should do it.